# How to get list of joined keys in jpa

Tags: java, jpa

How can I get a list of pictures_id in my Event Object?

[image: structure]

```
@Entity
public class Event {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String title;
    private String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date starttime;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date endtime;

    // add List<Long> picture_ids

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
    private List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
}
```

I want to be able to fetch the Event without the whole picture Objects since they're pretty big. But I can't find a solution to just query the keys to the pictures.

Comment: I wonder if you can try from `Picture` as it has event id for any entity.

Answer (score -1):

@LazyCollection is a hibernate specific annotation and will only work using Hibernate as JPA Providor.

The @OneToMany annotation is pure JPA, so it will work with any Jpa Providor.

You can achieve lazy loading only using @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Picture> pictures = new ArrayList<Picture>();
```

Comment: Check for @ElementCollection. Its the annotation you're looking for to use with List of Long.